# iOS passing string to another app

Tags: ios, string

I know it can pass file through Interaction Controller.
But is there a way to pass a plain text (string) to another app like "Open in.."?
I know Android can do it. But how about iOS?

EDIT:
I am not trying to open in a custom app handles my strings. I would like to open in those app that support string handling in entire system.

Comment: That totally depends on the app you want to open. You can use the app url scheme, which some times allows you to pass parameters.

Comment: @rckoenes: Yes, I missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do the below 2 steps in application-A:**

Step-1:

- Open "Supporting Files" (folder) on left and click the
  "YourAppName-Info.plist"
- Choose a row like "Bundle creator OS Type
  Code" and mouse over row and click the (+) symbol This creates a new
  row and type "URL types"
- Click the arror to left and see Item 0 and
  you'll rename the value in Item 0 to "URL Schemes" as shown
- Then edit
  the field in Item 0 and type "testURLScheme"[image]

Step-2:
Add this URL callback method in the same application,

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{

        if ([url.scheme caseInsensitiveCompare: @"testURLScheme"]==NSOrderedSame){
            NSArray *params = [url.query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
            NSArray *paramNameAndValue = [params[0] componentsSeparatedByString: @"="];
        }
    }
```

**Do this in application-B, Call the below piece of code:**

```
NSString *stringURL = @"testURLScheme://optionalAdress?paramName=stringToSend";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom URLs for that. In your app you call:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourcustomurl://?param1=value&param2=value2"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

On the app that will have to handle params you can get it here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    //depending of your format you can get them from one of NSURL methods:
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    NSString *parameters = [url parameterString];
    NSString *query = [url query];
}
```

Read more on:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50